# SQL Server 2008 Pivot query - replace output based on if there is a record and value from other field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following query that works great, but was wanting to know if I can change the Pivot results.

Here is a sample of the current output:

```
SERIAL_ID  Test_1  Test_2  Test_3  Test_4  Test_5    Test_6
12398701   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    Memory_1  NULL
```

Here is my desired output. If TEST_AREA is NULL and does not have TEST_RESULT = PASS or FAIL (no record) display INC. And, If TEST_RESULT = PASS replace NULL with PASS. Example below Test_3 and Test_6 did not run (no record)

```
SERIAL_ID  Test_1  Test_2  Test_3  Test_4  Test_5    Test_6
12398701   PASS    PASS    INC     PASS    Memory_1  INC
```

Here is the Query that I need modified:

```
select SERIAL_ID, Test_1, Test_2, Test_3, Test_4, Test_5, Test_6
from
(
  select SERIAL_ID, FAIL_CODE, TEST_AREA
  from
  (
    select f1.SERIAL_ID, f1.FAIL_CODE, f1.TEST_AREA, f1.TEST_RESULT,
      row_number() over(partition by f1.SERIAL_ID, f1.TEST_AREA
                        order by f1.TEST_DATE desc) seq
    from dbo_TBL_DM_TEST_RESULTS_Flex f1
    where f1.TEST_DATE> '2013-07-01' 
  ) d
  where seq = 1
    and (TEST_RESULT='fail' or TEST_RESULT='Pass') 
) d
pivot
(
    max(FAIL_CODE)
    for TEST_AREA in (Test_1, Test_2, Test_3, Test_4, Test_5, Test_6)
) piv;
```

Here is example of data:

```
TEST_AREA TEST_DATE              SERIAL_ID  TEST_RESULT  FAIL_CODE
Test_1    8/14/2013 11:29:24 AM  12398701   PASS         NULL
Test_2    8/17/2013 08:49:35 AM  12398701   PASS         NULL
Test_2    8/17/2013 10:15:38 PM  12398701   PASS         NULL
Test_4    8/17/2013 10:23:22 PM  12398701   FAIL         Pwr_up
Test_4    8/17/2013 10:24:22 PM  12398701   PASS         NULL
Test_5    8/18/2013 07:30:19 AM  12398701   FAIL         Pwr_up
Test_5    8/18/2013 07:34:34 AM  12398701   FAIL         Memory_1
```

Comment: Can you have a record with `Test_Result = FAIL and Fail_Code = Null`?

Comment: No, If the Test_Result is FAIL, you will have always have something in the Fail_Code (never NULL).  Test_Result = PASS will always have NULL in Fail_Code (want query to display PASS instead of NULL for Fail_Code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This relies on your test result/fail code either being Pass, Null or Fail, Not Null. It's a  bit brute force, but you're limited on what you can do inside a pivot:

```
select 
  serial_id, 
  IsNull(Test_1, 'INC') Test_1, 
  IsNull(Test_2, 'INC') Test_2,
  IsNull(Test_3, 'INC') Test_3,
  IsNull(Test_4, 'INC') Test_4,
  IsNull(Test_5, 'INC') Test_5,
  IsNull(Test_6, 'INC') Test_6
from (
  select
    serial_id,
    IsNull(fail_code, test_result) fail_code, -- propagate 'Pass' up
    test_area
  from (
    select
      f1.serial_id,
      f1.fail_code,
      f1.test_area,
      f1.test_result,
      row_number() over (
        partition by 
          f1.serial_id,
          f1.test_area
        order by
           f1.test_date desc
      ) seq
    from 
      dbo_tbl_dm_test_results_flex f1
    where
      f1.test_date > '2013-07-01' 
    ) d
  where 
    seq = 1 and 
    test_result in ('fail', 'Pass') 
  ) d
pivot (
    max(fail_code)
    for test_area in (Test_1, Test_2, Test_3, Test_4, Test_5, Test_6)
) piv;
```

**<kbd>[Example Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8f56d/1)</kbd>**

Comment: Thanks, Laurence... it works great.   Can you explain what the code is doing (I'm trying to learn SQL)?  Thanks.

Comment: @JimA Start from the inside and work out. So in this case, start with the select that has the alias `d`. Run this on its own. Imagine the result of this query was a table in it's own right, move up to the next query...

Comment: Is there a way to extract data from the serial_id field and display it as another field in the query output?  example: the serial_id has a date code in it (first 4 char) and I would like to output this value at the end of the record (field called Date_code).